# Processing nested json data into data joins

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I recently decided to use nested json, however, I cannot access them. I have seen some examples of different way to return data using the data method e.g.:

```
 var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
 .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.world;})

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
 .data(nodes)
```

However, this has had no affect. Therefore I've also tried:

```
 .text(function(d) { return d.world.Name; })
```

But I still havent had any luck!

Here's a snippet of the nested json:

```
           var nodes = {"Galaxy":"Milkyway","life":true,"world": [
         {"Name": 'Amy', "Country": 'USA', "translate":"translate(190,83)" }, 
         {"Name": 'Nathan', "Country": 'USA', "type": 'square', "translate":  "translate(190,83)"}, 
         {"Name": 'Lewis', "Country": 'USA', "type": 'circle', "translate":  "translate(20,183)" }, 
         {"Name": 'Tom', "Country": 'Japan', "type": 'diamond', "translate":  "translate(-300,-200)"},
         {"Name": 'Matt', "Country": 'Russia', "type": 'cross', "translate": "translate(10,183)"},
         {"Name": 'Frank', "Country": 'France', "type": 'triangle-up', "translate": "translate(30,183)"},
         {"Name": 'Bob', "Country": 'Japan', "type": 'diamond', "translate": "translate(10,13)"}
]};
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The form of `.data` function you used in the first instance is meant to be used for object consistency by assigning [`keys` to each data item](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data). `.data` does not follow the same accessor pattern as `d3.max`, `d3.mean`, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. is it possible that you could show me an example?

Comment: This example from mbostock himself would be helpful to understand how the _key_ functionality works: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found an appropriate solution to my problem:

```
   var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                 .data(nodes.world)
```

Please, if you have another I'm open to other ways of doing things. Thanks :)